# How can I convert rows to columns using Pivot?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have data in tableA that can have multiple rows for our clients. Each row has a code for the invoice purchase. I would like to return one single row for each client with columns for each invoice type equal to '100' and '18'. The image below shows how the table returns the results, toward the bottom is what I would like returned.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaOfM.png)

I am using this link as guidance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNetxDl40pM&ab_channel=Teradata

This is what I have:

```
select * from mytable1 pivot (max(client) FOR Invoice IN (18, 100) TEST ORDER BY 1
```

I ran the query but it did not return what I am expecting.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes:  
Please in code questions give
Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Put all that's needed to ask your question in your post. Don't expect readers to read entire other pages & guess what's relevant & why. Especially not videos. Quote/paraphrase with credit & relate to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want multiple columns to be pivoted so you need to include multiple columns in the pivot:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable1
PIVOT (
  MAX(descr) AS descr,
  MAX(amount) AS amount,
  MAX(date_paid) AS date_paid
  FOR Invoice IN (
    18  AS INV18,
    100 AS INV100
  )
)
ORDER BY client
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable1 (client, invoice, descr, amount, date_paid) AS
SELECT 123456, 100, 'car',   600, DATE '2020-01-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456,  18, 'truck', 800, DATE '2020-01-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456,   1, 'toy',   500, DATE '2020-01-05' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CLIENT | INV18_DESCR | INV18_AMOUNT | INV18_DATE_PAID | INV100_DESCR | INV100_AMOUNT | INV100_DATE_PAID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | truck | 800 | 2020-01-29 00:00:00 | car | 600 | 2020-01-23 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TsH4u6Gt)